# Transistor switch with capacitive load

Tags: transistors, mosfet, capacitor

## The goal

I would like to know how to connect a transistor (MOSFET) to a capacitive load. I would like to rapidly charge and discharge a capacitor.

**How do I do it correctly? I basically want the transistor to work as a mechanical switch.**

[image]

## What I have tried so far

I have tried the following circuit, but for some reason, VDS (voltage, drain-source) is always zero. Here VDS = V_cap (Voltage over the capacitor)

[image]

Here is a transient analysis:

[image]

### The issue:

As you can see VDS is always zero. I expect it to be alternating.

## Additional Material

- Download the [TINA](https://www.ti.com/tool/TINA-TI) simulation [here.](https://filebin.net/hfjnb98u0isxwrep)
- I used this [MOSFET.](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91023/91023.pdf)

**EDIT:**

As suggested, putting a small Resistor (here I put 10Ohms) in parallel solves the issue:

[image]

[image]

... but **I don't understand why?** Wouldn't we have a floating node if the transistor is open?
[image]

Comment: @JRE Thanks for the edit!

Comment: The second circuit is not the same as the first. do you want to switch the high side or the low side?

Comment: Regarding your edited question: capacitor and bleeding resistor form a closed circuit. What is floating is the charging part of the circuit.

Comment: One example of a circuit specialized for driving capacitive loads is what's called a gate driver, so called because its main purpose is to quickly and decisively drive the gate of a FET or IGBT (which is capacitive in nature).

Comment: @Hearth Many thanks for your comment. I don't have much experience with that. Do you have a reference where this is used to drive a capacitive load? Thanks

Comment: @SredniVashtar Yes, but to me, it seems that the capacitor and the resistor circuit are not attached to the ground. Hence, there should be no charge redistribution across the capacitor. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It does not matter whether or not they are attached to a node you arbitrarily named "ground". What matters is that they are connected in a circuit that allows for current to flow. Every circuit is floating with respect to any point not connected to it. Simulation software require you to specifiy at least one ground point for 'mathematical' reasons, but, paraphrasing Paul Young, ground is... wherever you lay your hat.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Sorry for bothering you and thanks for the explanation. However, I still don't quite get it: Let me explain: To me, the capacitor and resistor are connected in series, and with nothing else than maybe the positive voltage of the power supply. Hence, I don't see why the electrons would flow? There is no voltage difference... or could you maybe pinpoint me to where there is a difference. Many thanks ! :)

Comment: When seen as a separated circuit R and C are both in series and in parallel. The potential difference is that across the charged capacitor (and it also happens to be across the resistor). Current can flow through the resistor and the capacitor will discharge with time constant RC. It does not matter if there is another part of the circuit called "ground". R and C have all it takes to form a closed circuit and make current flow.

Answer (score 3):

To observe a VDS of 5V you must have some way of reducing the voltage **across** the capacitor to zero. Your circuit has no path for current flow to accomplish that. Try putting a resistor in **parallel** with the capacitor and you should see VDS change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Very much appreciated! However, I don't fully understand what happens if the MOSFET is in the open state. Wouldn't that produce a floating node? (see EDIT in the question).

Comment: Yes, it is floating so its voltage does not change. The first time you closed the switch/mosfet you brought one end of the capacitor to ground, which meant that the voltage **across** the capacitor was 5V. When you open the switch/mosfet one end of the capacitor is floating, so the voltage across the capacitor never changes...it is still 5V...so the voltage at the left end of the capacitor is still 0.

Comment: By the way, the usual way this site works is that the person who asks a question will "accept" an answer that most helps them or solves their problem. The people who write answers really appreciate that feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I will accept the answer as soon as I have understood it. So far I still have troubles with the floating node. Correct me if I am wrong, but you are essentially saying that the voltage across the capacitor -once charged- will always stay 5V. Why is it then that I see those charge/discharge cycles in the simulation (see the plot in the edit)? Thanks a lot for your help.